# getsnapshot returns a cyan screen

Tags: matlab

I run this code in MATLAB but it returns a Cyan frame

```
obj = videoinput('winvideo', 1);

% Select the source to use for acquisition. 
set(obj, 'SelectedSourceName', 'input1')

% View the properties for the selected video source object.
src_obj = getselectedsource(obj);
get(src_obj)

% Acquire and display a single image frame.
frame = getsnapshot(obj);
image(frame);

% Remove video input object from memory.
delete(obj);
```

But preview video works well.[image: getsnapshot output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `obj.ReturnedColorSpace = 'rgb';` in the second line solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is with the input to `image` command.

Try to run

```
 class(frame)
 max(frame(:))
 min(frame(:))
```

And see what the results are.

Double values should be between `[0-1]`, whereas `uint8` should be in the range of `[0-255].`

Comment: `ans = uint8
ans =  136
ans =   18`